# How can I configure log4net to display the call stack & inner exception

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

What I want is basic, to have the log display the InnerException(s) for an exception and the call stack for each.

My configuration is:

```xml
<log4net debug="false">
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:\temp\DotNetEngine.log" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="2" />
        <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="500KB" />
        <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
        <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%exception%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

But all I get is:

> 2019-05-06 16:28:28,042 [1] ERROR
>   RunReport.net.windward.samples.RunReport -
>   RunReportnet.windward.env.DataSourceException: Could not load file:
>   c:\test\xyz.docx; subtype=INVALID_FILENAME;

And the above exception does have an InnerException (verified with the debugger).

I am using log4net 2.0.8 which is the latest

Comment: How does your code look like? How do you logging this exception? Add sample to your question please.

Comment: @Peska standard log.warn(ex.getMessage(), ex);

Comment: getMessage() method? On Exception object? Does it contains stack trace? Try `log.Error(ex);`

Comment: @Peska We are using IKVM for some of this so java Throwable.getMessage(). But I did it in some C# code with log.Error("Run Report", ex);  Also, log.Error(ex) just does a ToString() on ex, it has to be the 2nd parameter to be treated as an exception object.

Comment: Are we talking about java or C# in here? Did you try my solution? From Exception.ToString() documentation: "The default implementation of ToString obtains the name of the class that threw the current exception, the message, the **result of calling ToString on the inner exception**, and the **result of calling Environment.StackTrace**. If any of these members is null, its value is not included in the returned string."

Comment: @Peska - Bingo! Ok, that solved it. We have Java code that is converted to .NET code using IKVM. However, I think what is happening is that log4net uses ToString() to get the full dump - and the Java exceptions don't do that in their toString().

Comment: @Peska BTW - posted what I think I need to do at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025988/how-can-i-take-over-writing-an-exception-in-log4net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following class to your code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Displays inner exceptions for log4net for Exceptions based on java.lang.Throwable. Needed because
/// System.Exception.ToString() returns the call stacks and inner exceptions. java.lang.Throwable does not.
/// </summary>
public class ThrowablePatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Write out the info for a logging event. Only writes for a java.lang.Throwable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The log output.</param>
    /// <param name="loggingEvent">The logging event - only if java.lang.Throwable</param>
    protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        Exception ex = loggingEvent.ExceptionObject as java.lang.Throwable;
        if (ex == null)
            return;
        bool first = true;
        while (ex != null)
        {
            if (! first)
                writer.Write($"Caused by: {ex.GetType().FullName}: ");
            first = false;
            writer.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            // call stack
            writer.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);

            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

And add the following to your config file:

```
                                        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                                                        <converter>
                                                                        <name value="throwable" />
                                                                        <type value="Kailua.net.windward.utils.ThrowablePatternConverter" />
                                                        </converter>
                                                        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%exception%throwable%newline" />
                                        </layout>
```