# How can I take over writing an exception in log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, ikvm

We have a large Java application that we convert to .NET using IKVM. All of the log4j calls in it call a log4j wrapper we created that calls log4net. Mostly it works great.

But we have one problem - the logging does not give the stack trace or InnerException(s). I believe the problem is the .NET Exception.ToString() provides all that information while the Java Throwable.toString() is basically the Exception.Message.

So where log4net calls Exception.ToString(), I need to replace that for any exception that inherits from java.lang.Throwable to create the string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `Exception.ToString()`, `Log4net` looks whether a custom [`IObjectRenderer`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_ObjectRenderer_IObjectRenderer.htm) has been registered for an `Exception` *(as it also does for any other type)*.

In order to get a custom `Exception` output, you need to create and register a custom `IObjectRenderer`.

The one here below will output the `Exception` in uppercase.
You are free to build any error message string representation which you pass to  `writer.Write`.

```
namespace PFX
{
    public class MyExceptionRenderer : IObjectRenderer
    {
        public void RenderObject(RendererMap rendererMap, object obj, TextWriter writer)
        {
            Exception exception = obj as Exception;
            // Format the error message as pleased here.
            String error = exception.ToString().ToUpper();
            writer.Write(error);
        }
    }
}
```

You register the `MyExceptionRenderer` in your `Log4net` configuration as shown below.

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >        
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">            
            <conversionPattern value="%date | %logger | %level | %message | %exception%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="All" />        
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </root>

    <renderer renderingClass="PFX.MyExceptionRenderer"
              renderedClass="System.Exception" />
</log4net>
```

The code below

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("AppLog");
var exception = new ApplicationException("Ooops");
logger.Error("An error occured.", exception);
```

will have the following log output.
Notice that the exception is in full caps.

```
2019-05-08 21:52:22,855 | AppLog | ERROR | An error occured. | SYSTEM.APPLICATIONEXCEPTION: OOOPS
```

Comment: Is this approach better/worse/same as adding a PatternLayoutConverter as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013190/how-can-i-configure-log4net-to-display-the-call-stack-inner-exception? I'm trying to understand how each works.

Comment: @DavidThielen In short, an `IObjectRenderer` ensures that the output of the object will always be as  expected, also when calling `logger.Debug(Object message)` passing in an `Exception` instance, whereas for a `PatternLayoutConverter` this will only work when using a `PatternLayout` containing the configured marker (as in your example `%throwable`).

Comment: Thanks for providing this full example. I was working off a different snippet and it wasn't working for me, my <renderer> was inside the <appender> element instead of its sibling. Full examples ftw.